# How do i change my appicon dynamically in react native for ios?

Tags: react-native

Ive noticed you can change your appicon dynamically in swift in xcode. I was wondering how I can also change my appicon dynamically in react native.

Comment: did you check this out: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dynamic-app-icon ? or are you asking to learn more about how to do so?

Comment: To add to @SamerMurad 's answer, there's another package that even works for Android apart from iOS: https://github.com/skb1129/react-native-change-icon